# how to make a WatiN internal http request?

Tags: c#, watin

just wonder whether it's possible to make an internal extra request to an image without using separate code. eg,

```
var browser = new IE();
string url = "https://www.google.com/"
browser.GoTo(url);

// extract http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png 
//using a http request using browser ?
```

`browser.Images` wont let me save the image :|, how can I make an external request to get the image ?

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the URL to your image, you can use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class in the `System.Net` namespace.

```
byte[] image = new WebClient().DownloadData("https://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png");
```

Comment: Thanks, my URL is a https URL, so i can't use WebClient(). isn't is possible to use the internal ref and make a separate internal call?

Comment: `WebClient` does work over https. I've never used WatiN before, so I'd have to check on that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these steps work:

- Find the image on the page:

```cs
var image = browser.Image(Find.First())
```

- Get the href and navigate to it

```cs
browser.GoTo(image.href);
```

- Get a screenshot of the page:

```cs
var screenshot= new UtilityClasses.CaptureWebPage(_browser).CaptureWebPageImage(false, false, 100);
```

- And then trim the screenshot to the size of the image. To get the Height and Width of the image you need the call

```cs
var width = image.Style.GetAttributeValue("width");
var height= image.Style.GetAttributeValue("height");
```

- Now you can create a new Image with the correct height and width.

HTH,
Jeroen

Comment: Jeroen, Thank you for the answer. it works for a normal image thats embadded in a webpage. in my case it's a captcha image. Is there a way to open a seperate tab and use this method? Thanks alot